# OpenMP Thread count question

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

So Im doing a bit of Parallel Programming of the Trapezoidal Rule for my OS class, this is a homework question but im not looking for source code.

after a bit of research I decided to use each thread to compute a subinterval.
using:

```
 g = (b-a)/n;
   integral += (func(a) + func(b))/2.0;

#  pragma omp parallel for schedule(static) default(none) \
      shared(a, h, n) private(i, x) \
      reduction(+: integral) num_threads(thread_count)
   for (i = 1; i <= n-1; i++) {
      x = a + i*g;
      integral += func(x);
   }
```

in my integral function, func(x) is the function that I read in from the file.

So I email my professor to ask how he wants to go about choosing the number of threads. (since they will need to be evenly divisible by N (for the trapezoidal rule)

but he is saying I dont need to define them, and it will define them based on the number of cores on my machine........So needless to say Im a bit confused.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your professor is correct: OpenMP will choose an optimum number of threads by default, which is usually the number of cores.

You don't need to worry about the number of threads being exactly divisible by N: OpenMP will automatically distribute the iterations among the threads, and if they're not evenly divisible, one thread will end up performing a little more or less work.

Comment: Ok So my program should work if I just take out the num_threads(thread count)? btw does default(none) even need to be defined

Comment: @Mercfh: No, but it might be a good idea since you have to explicitly declare the sharing in that case. The initial default sharing differs between C++ and Fortran so being explicit helps with porting.

Comment: @pafcu, your saying NO to the Default thing right? also I can just take out the num_threads(thread count) and the compiler should take care of it correct?

Comment: @Mercfh: Sorry I was unclear. Yes I meant that default(none) is not needed (but it's still a good idea to keep it to ease porting). The answer by casablanca is correct, you can leave num_threads out. Oh, and it's not the compiler but the runtime that takes care of choosing the right amount of threads.